# Fast infantry training

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

Which civilization is having most upgrades for speed up infantry training (**reducing training time**)?
Example: researches, cards, unique upgrades, etc.

Comment: AOE 2 had Goths!

Answer (score 3):

Russians can reduce infantry training time to **zero**
3 cards are required -

1. fencing school (reduce training point -40%)
2. Team dueling school (reduce training point -25%)
3. Reformist TSAR . This will set a unique upgrade (standing army) in your church as obtainable

Comment: what about native civilizations in expansions (Asian dynasties)?They perform a dance to speed up unit training